# Ensure that something is stored in Session before anything else in the Page Life Cycle

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, page-lifecycle

I want to store something in the Session object (i.e. a user ID), before anything else happens in a Page's Life Cycle.
I tried putting it in the Page's constructor, but the Session object isn't yet available then.
I tried overriding `OnInit`, but then other delegates hooked to the `Init` event might still be executed prior.

I'm really lost, even though this feels like very basic ASP.NET theory.

Comment: @Aristos: Wouldn't that give me the exact same issues, but with delegates also hooked to PreInit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A more usual approach is to encapsulate access to the data in Session, and load it on demand the first time it's accessed.  The basic pattern looks like the following:

```
public string UserId
{
    get
    {
        string s = Session["UserId"];
        if (s == null)
        {
            s = ... Get UserID from somewhere, e.g. database
            Session["UserId"] = s;
        }
        return s;
    }
}
```

In this way the data will be loaded the first time it's needed, and you don't need to care when that is in the page lifecycle.

Comment: Ah, this is great! Not an answer to the question I guess, but possibly a much better solution to the problem! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can override the [OnInit()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.oninit.aspx) method, implement your code, and add a final call to base.OnInit() which raises the registered Init events.

Comment: Actually, the other registered delegates are going to be executed regardless if you call the base's OnInit or not. To see what I mean, in the Page's constructor put something like this: `Init += MyDelegate;`.

Comment: can't check .net right now, but have a look at Mono and search for OnInit http://www.koders.com/csharp/fidAA56C9C1D467513563E334F597BC2EAE269C9C18.aspx